# How to label occurences of text?

Tags: bash, sed, awk, text-processing

I would like to convert

```
blue blue red green
```

to:

```
color.1=blue color.2=blue color.3=red color.4=green
```

Any leads on how to tackle this? sed, awk, etc.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Bash:

```
colors="blue blue red green"
i=1
for c in $colors; do
    echo -n "color.$((i++))=$c "
done
```

Command-line version (easy to copy&paste to terminal) with 2 lines - setting variables first and then main script:

```
colors="blue blue red green"; i=1
for c in $colors; do echo -n "color.$((i++))=$c "; done
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Python way:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
input_string = 'blue blue red green'
count = 1
for value in input_string.split():
    print 'color.{0}={1}'.format(count, value),
    count += 1
```

**Output:** `color.1=blue color.2=blue color.3=red color.4=green`

Here is a `sed` way:

```
$ n=1;x=color;echo "blue blue red green" | sed -rn "s/^([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)$/$x\.$n=\1 $x\.$((n+1))=\2 $x\.$((n+2))=\3 $x\.$((n+3))=\4/p"
```

**Output:** `color.1=blue color.2=blue color.3=red color.4=green`

Here we have used the variable `n` to store `1` and `x` to store the string `color`, then used the grouping and backreferencing to get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative python way, right now I am just using bash so I will use madneon's answer, your answer is appreciated, cheers!

Comment: @user264974: Sure, feel free.. :)

Comment: @user264974: check out the newly added `sed` way (if that helps)..

Answer (score 3):

Here is [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution if your colors are so more:

```bsh
awk '{ printf("color.%d=%s ",NR, $0 ) }' RS='[[:blank:]]+' infile
color.1=blue color.2=blue color.3=red color.4=green
```

`RS` defines Spaces/Tabs as **R**ecord **S**eparator with occurrences of one or more times `+`. Then the `printf` command print the current **N**umber of **R**ecord/field and next print the whole record/field `$0` from *infile* as input file.